# How to construct object without allocating its memory?

Tags: delphi

I would like objects contained within other objects not to have to allocate their memory. For example in Delphi I could write this:

```pascal
type
  TTest = class
    obj1: tobject1;
    obj2: tobject2;
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

constructor TTest.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  obj1 := tobject1.Create;
  obj2 := tobject2.Create;
end;

destructor TTest.Destroy;
begin
  obj1.Free;
  obj2.Free;
  inherited;
end;
```

Similar C++ code would look like this:

```cpp
class TTest {
    tobject1 obj1;
    tobject2 obj2;
};
```

The difference I'd like to focus on is how in the Delphi version there's 3 memory allocations while there is only 1 in the C++ version. Is there a way to only have a single memory allocation in Delphi for a complete object and its sub-objects, like it is in C++?

**Update**: Full C++ test code:

```cpp
class tobject1 { public: int aaa; };
class tobject2 { public: int bbb; };

class TTest {
    tobject1 obj1;
    tobject2 obj2;
public:
    void doThing() { obj1.aaa = obj2.bbb; };
};

int main()
{
    {TTest * test = new TTest; test->doThing(); delete test; }
    {TTest test; test.doThing(); }

    return 0;
}
```

Disassembled code:

```
{TTest * test = new TTest; test->doThing(); delete test; }
013D182E  push        8  
013D1830  call        operator new (013D1299h)  
013D1835  add         esp,4  
013D1838  mov         dword ptr [ebp-0E4h],eax  
013D183E  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-0E4h]  
013D1844  mov         dword ptr [ebp-8],eax  
013D1847  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-8]  
013D184A  call        TTest::doThing (013D133Eh)  
013D184F  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-8]  
013D1852  mov         dword ptr [ebp-0F0h],eax  
013D1858  push        8  
013D185A  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-0F0h]  
013D1860  push        ecx  
013D1861  call        operator delete (013D104Bh)  
013D1866  add         esp,8  
{TTest test; test.doThing(); }
013D1869  lea         ecx,[ebp-18h]  
013D186C  call        TTest::doThing (013D133Eh)
```

The c++ object only needs 1 memory allocation for a new object that contains sub-objects, and even 0 memory allocations if object was put on the stack rather than heap.

**Update**: Full Delphi test code:

```pascal
program Project1;

type
  tobject1 = class
    aaa: longint;
  end;

  tobject2 = class
    bbb: longint;
  end;

  TTest = class
    obj1: tobject1;
    obj2: tobject2;
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure doThing;
  end;

constructor TTest.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  obj1 := tobject1.Create;
  obj2 := tobject2.Create;
end;

destructor TTest.Destroy;
begin
  obj1.Free;
  obj2.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TTest.doThing;
begin
  obj1.aaa := obj2.bbb;
end;

var
  test: TTest;

begin
  test := TTest.Create;
  test.doThing;
  test.Free;
end.
```

Disassembled allocation code:

```
Project1.dpr.35: test := TTest.Create;
0040A0F4 B201             mov dl,$01
0040A0F6 A19C924000       mov eax,[$0040929c]
0040A0FB E8DCF2FFFF       call TTest.Create
0040A100 A3F8F44000       mov [$0040f4f8],eax
Project1.dpr.36: test.doThing;
0040A105 A1F8F44000       mov eax,[$0040f4f8]
0040A10A E865F3FFFF       call TTest.doThing
Project1.dpr.37: test.Free;
0040A10F A1F8F44000       mov eax,[$0040f4f8]
0040A114 E8DBA1FFFF       call TObject.Free
```

Disassembled creation code code:

```
Project1.dpr.16: obj1 := tobject1.Create;
004093F4 B201             mov dl,$01
004093F6 A144914000       mov eax,[$00409144]
004093FB E8C4AEFFFF       call TObject.Create
00409400 8B55FC           mov edx,[ebp-$04]
00409403 894204           mov [edx+$04],eax
Project1.dpr.17: obj2 := tobject2.Create;
00409406 B201             mov dl,$01
00409408 A1F0914000       mov eax,[$004091f0]
0040940D E8B2AEFFFF       call TObject.Create
00409412 8B55FC           mov edx,[ebp-$04]
00409415 894208           mov [edx+$08],eax
```

This Delphi object needs 3 memory allocations for a new object that contains 2 sub-objects. Is it possible to reduce to one allocation like in C++ (or even 0 if put on the stack) using objects not records (which aren't the same at all since they don't support inheritance)?

Comment: There are three memory allocations in c++ version as well. Default constructors of `tobject1` and `tobject2` are called in the `TTest` constructor. Delphi does not have this mechanism, so you have to create objects manually.

Comment: default constructors and destructors are called on sub-objects, but not new and delete, the c++ version only allocates one block of memory for the whole object composition.

Comment: I've never tried it but you could play with overriding [TObject.NewInstance](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.TObject.NewInstance). But be aware that's not the Delphi way.

Comment: Another possibility is using `record`s which are value types like C++ `struct`s, whereas delphi `class`es are reference types like in C#/Java.

Comment: What you would like is not doable with class instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Delphi classes are reference types and so always incur a heap location when instantiated. So you can't achieve the memory layout that you wish using classes.

Records, by contrast, are value types. If you make your two embedded types into records then the memory will be laid out as you wish, and there will be just a single heap allocation.

Comment: I think your first paragraph you meant "can't"? I was hoping it was possible to do like your second paragraph but also be able to use inheritance with the embedded types, but if not then alright.

Comment: Inheritance of values opens you up to [object slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing). And yes, I corrected the first paragraph, thanks.

Comment: You could declare the types as `object` instead of `class` or `record`. An `object` can be allocated on the stack, and the nested objects would all be in one allocation, similar to the C++ code. However, `object` is old syntax provided for backwards compatibility, `record` types would be preferred in this situation.

Comment: When i last tried type object some years ago they worked fine in freepascal but had various bugs in delphi, so I didnt think to try them again. I'll try it and if they work now will report back.

Comment: Minimal tests, but looks like object type works but is really weird. It can inherit and access parent members but can't override virtual functions, constructors/destructors don't work, class functions don't work.

Comment: `object` is deprecated since years, so not much "new" stuff will work. Overriding **does** work but you have to mark the overriding method as `virtual`, **not** `override`. But you can't use inheritance anyway in your scenario (due to object slicing as David mentioned) so you can use `record` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking wrong here. C++ knows constructors and destructors just as does Delphi, you just didn't define them in your C++ definition.

And no, you can't allocate an instance of a class without allocating memory for that instance. 
That's also no different between Delphi and C++.

Comment: In the c++ version, when creating a new TTest object, there will be only one memory allocation for the whole object, with constructors being called for main object and each sub-object. I would like that behavior in Delphi.

Comment: @Mardulu:That is not how *classes* work in Delphi. I probably shouldn't mention them, but the old Turbo Pascal `object` types are much more like C++ classes, and can be used as value types, but even they are not automatically constructed. Note that these old style `object` types are deprecated and not fully supported anymore.